# Filter Angular JS ng-options by array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'd like to filter ng-options whith an array. By example :

```
<select
    ng-model="currentItem.Community.white_label_id"
    ng-options="whitelabel.WhiteLabel.id as whitelabel.WhiteLabel.name for whitelabel in whitelabels | filter:whitelabel.WhiteLabel.id in currentWhiteLabel.affiliatedids"
>
```

currentWhiteLabel.affiliatedids looks like [73,71]

How can i do that ?

Comment: Are you able to share some example data?

Comment: whitelabels is an array such as {"WhiteLabel":{"id":28,"name":"abd","code":"abc","type":"collectivity","active":true,"embedded":false,"subdomain":"","website":"http://dqsfsdf.com","help_website":null,"email_auto":"fffff@yopmail.com"}}. Ng-options are good, but I can't filter them with the array

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a solution, but by using ng-repeat in the options. Hope this will help someone :

```
option value="whitelabel.WhiteLabel.id" ng-repeat="whitelabel in whitelabels" ng-if="currentWhiteLabel.affiliatedids.indexOf(whitelabel.WhiteLabel.id) != -1">{{whitelabel.WhiteLabel.name}}</option>
```